# Scattering of waves by an obstacle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, symplectic-geometry

I wish to study the paper by Melroe and Taylor: Near peak scattering and the corrected Kirchhoff approximation for a convex obstacle. Adv in Math, Vol 55 (3), 1985, 242–315.
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870885900933
Although I have some background in pseudodifferential operators and symplectic geometry, and I can read parts of the article (phase stationary phases…) ; I have some doubts to understand the very long paper, especially the symplectic part (pages 260-268).

Would you please help me with the following:

1) what is a Whitney fold? (I searched google, wikipedia without success).

2) how they construct the involutions $J_1,J_2$ in page 261?

3) What are the illuminated, shadow region and the shadow boundary?

Thank you!

Comment: Whitney folds are singularities of a smooth mapping. The original definition was given [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970070).

Comment: For a more modern perspective, a reference is [this](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=341518).

Comment: Thank you Willie. I found also the book by Yung-Chen Lu, Singularity Theory and an Introduction to Catastrophe Theory, very useful for the study of singularities.

Comment: This paper is also very interesting! http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319521